# Open fancybox when another function calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, fancybox

I have a container which will be open in fancy box.

```
<div id="fancyPopup">
 Fancy Box Content
</div>
```

Now i want to open this fancy box when another function calls:

```
function calc()
{

 // Fancy box should open now

}
```

How can I implement this ?

**Here is my fancy box script:**

```
function showPopup() {
    $('#fromDate').val('2013-11-03');
    $('#toDate').val('2013-11-06');

    $("#fancyPopup").fancybox({
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none',
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this :

```
$("#fancyPopup").fancybox({
    openEffect: 'none',
    closeEffect: 'none',
});
```

because the selector `#fancyPopup` becomes the **trigger** and the **target** of fancybox.

You could rather do this

```
function calc() {
    // Fancy box should open now
    showPopup();
}

function showPopup() {
    $('#fromDate').val('2013-11-03');
    $('#toDate').val('2013-11-06');
    $.fancybox("#fancyPopup", {
        // API options here
        openEffect: 'none',
        closeEffect: 'none'
    });
}
```

See <kbd>[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/v9q3Y/)</kbd>

Answer (score -1):

Try calling with  [`$.fancybox.open( \[group\], \[options\] )`](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs) mentioned in documentation.

```
function openFancy()
{   
    $.fancybox($("#fancyPopup")).open([
            {         
                title : '1st title'
            }
        ]);
}
```

[From Documentation:](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/#docs)

**open()**

```
$.fancybox.open( [group], [options] )
```

Launch fancyBox, the same as `$.fancybox([group], [options])`
First parameter can be in various types,

examples:

> ```
> $.fancybox([ {href : 'img1.jpg', title : 'Title'}, {href : 'img2.jpg'
>   ,title : 'Title'} ]); - array containing objects
>
> $.fancybox( {href : 'image.jpg', title : 'Lorem lipsum'} ); - single object
>
> $.fancybox( ['image.jpg', 'image.jpg'] ); - array containing links as strings
>
> $.fancybox( 'image.jpg' ); - string as source link 
> $.fancybox( [jQuery object] );
> $.fancybox( "<h1>Lorem lipsum</h1>" );
> ```

**[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/STgGM/1802/)**

Comment: @CodeHunter, please check my updated answer with demo